# Accent/Pronunciation Feedback Software for German

Tags: pronunciation, german, accent-reduction, software

**Is there software that can listen to a sample of my German speech and give feedback on my accent and pronunciation?**

I wish to have an impartial party listen to my speech, so that I can determine whether I would pass for a German/Swiss person or whether it would be obvious to a native that I was foreign.

I wish to have a machine do this, since I would be querying it far too many times to be constantly asking humans. I would use this tool to carefully tune the way I pronounce phonetic syllables. I am early in the learning process of this language (not even level A1.1 yet) but I am particularly concerned about pronunciation more than anything. I believe this will help me to attain a neutral German accent in the future as per [this answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3176/is-it-possible-for-an-adult-to-learn-a-language-without-carrying-a-foreign-accen).

There is no doubt in my mind that the technical capability exists to create such software given all of Google's data, but I was not able to find such software myself.

(I would love if this software also taught the phonetic alphabet at the same time!)

---

Similar question in the context of learning English, and which was never answered: [Is there software that can determine whether I speak with a neutral accent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178/is-there-software-that-can-determine-whether-i-speak-with-a-neutral-accent).

Comment: The question is perfectly on topic on this site, so why should it be migrated?

Comment: *[...] give feedback on my accent and pronunciation [...] so that I can determine whether I would pass for a German/Swiss person.* **How's your rate on gender errors?** Less than one out of thousand nouns spoken? Congrats, you pass as a native speaker, regardless of your pronounciation. You may even roll your **R**s, and people would simply assume your mother is from Austria or Sudeten. German Dialects differ that much pronounciation isn't a reliable marker for native speakers. Get the noun genders right, even professional second-language speakers usually make one gender error every few senten

Comment: @Janka Please do not use answers for commenting on questions.

Comment: The reason I did not use a comment was it is now truncated.

Answer (score -1):

Pronunciation coach. Cost about 35 US and you can dl a free trial. I have tested with my own American English accent and German natives and it is reliable. http://www.rose-medical.com/pronunciation-coach.html

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Please be aware that this is not a forum (take the [tour] and read [How do I write a good answer?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)), so answers need to be on topic. A question asking for *software* should not be answered by recommending a coach.

Comment: Welcome. Are you affiliated  with the website in question? It is okay to share such links if you disclose your affiliation or lack thereof.
Also, a few more words about what the software actually does would improve this answer significantly.

Comment: Good suggestion however I find it completely useless with German. I have a high quality microphone, I say "heruntergeladen" almost flawlessly, and it thinks I say "das IAE" or  "A lagen" or "ja die Laden" etc. I will say something exactly the same way several times and the speech intelligibility score it assigns is seemingly random.

It seems to rely on the text-to-speech and speech recognition packages that ship with Windows. The "Model Pronunciation" tab is also non-functional in German for me, apart from playing a synthesised voice.